# Java file generated by a genrule not included into compiling procedure

Tags: buck

I face a problem in buck gen_rule usage.

I have a executable jar file, called SqlDelightBin, which could generate Java source files, during gradle build process, there will be a gradle task to run this jar file, and the generated Java files could be compiled properly.

But when I wrap this jar file with a gen_rule, named sqldelight_devDebug, and add it into my android_library’s deps list, although this gen_rule runs properly, but the generated Java files are not compiled in this compile round, so the generated class could not be found, when I run the buck build command again, it succeed.

My gen_rule is:

```
genrule(
    name = 'sqldelight_devDebug',
    srcs = glob([
        'src/*/sqldelight/**/*.sq',
    ]),
    out = 'out',
    bash = 'java -jar /Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/.okbuck/cache/c61171f7a8bee5d459102d49daecb0b6/SqlDelightBin-0.4.3.jar $SRCDIR /Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/app/build/okbuck/sqldelight && echo $SRCS > $OUT',
)
```

It run the jar file, which will compile SQL files in `src/*/sqldelight/` to Java files in `/Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/app/build/okbuck/sqldelight` dir, and to make BUCK think this genrule succeed, we create the `$OUT` file with SQL file list.

My android_library is:

```
android_library(
    name = 'src_devDebug',
    srcs = glob([
        'src/main/java/**/*.java',
        'build/okbuck/sqldelight/**/*.java’, # the generated Java files
        'src/dev/java/**/*.java',
    ]),
    # other params
    deps = [
        # other deps
        ':sqldelight_devDebug',
    ],
    visibility = [
        'PUBLIC',
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the file generated by the `sqldelight_devDebug` target as a source, add that target name to `srcs`, like this:

```
android_library(
    name = 'src_devDebug',
    srcs = [
        ':sqldelight_devDebug',
    ] + glob([
        'src/main/java/**/*.java',
        'src/dev/java/**/*.java',
    ]),
    # other params
    deps = [
        # other deps
    ],
    visibility = [
        'PUBLIC',
    ],
)
```

Comment: Not as part of the `glob` though; I'm pretty sure that would not get picked up.  You'd want to add it to the result of the `glob`.

Comment: By making `srcs = [':sqldelight_devDebug'] + glob(['src/main/java/**/*.java', 'src/dev/java/**/*.java']),`, and change my genrule's bash into `bash = 'java -jar /Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/.okbuck/cache/c61171f7a8bee5d459102d49daecb0b6/SqlDelightBin-0.4.3.jar $SRCDIR /Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/app/build/okbuck/sqldelight > $OUT',`, it print the generated Java file list into `$OUT`, after I run `buck build`, the `__src_devDebug__srcs` file has one line of the `$OUT` file path, but the compile still fail with generated class not found. Should the new added line be `@$OUT`, so it can look recursively?

Comment: But I don't know how to make this happen, thanks for your help! @sdwilsh

Comment: @sdwilsh, you are right, I missed that. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Piasy, if the genrule generates multiple source files, it gets a bit more complicated. I think one possible approach is to make the genrule create a `.src.zip` file containing the generated sources and use that as a source in the java_library.

Comment: And if you do that, you'll want to use the `zip_file` rule in order to get a deterministic build.  The `genrule` would need to output a folder then, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks! By making my genrule create a zip file containing the generated sources, I succeed. @sdwilsh But I don't use zip_file rule, I run the zip command directly, so my genrule's bash is: `bash = 'java -jar /Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/.okbuck/cache/SqlDelightBin-0.4.3.jar $SRCDIR /Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/app/build/okbuck/sqldelight && zip -r $OUT /Users/piasy/src/OkBuck/app/build/okbuck/sqldelight',`, would this have any problem?

Comment: The zip command usually includes some non-deterministic information in the archive, for example the last modification time of the files. This means that the output is not stable and the rules that depend on this rule might not get cache hits even if the generated sources did not change. Buck's `zip_file` rule makes sure that its output is exactly the same every time you run it as long as the sources do not change.